# How to create a collection view with static cells only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to add a vertical collection view that contains 7 static cells. I know how to do it dynamically, but i don't see a reason to do so.

Do i have to use the cellForRow method? 
I Added a collection view to my viewController, and added 4 cells, wired up the delegate from the collectionView to the vc (using storyBoard), but when i run it it shows me an empty collectionView.

I did set up the numberOfSections to return 1 and the numberOfCellsInSection to return 7. So did i miss anything? or do i have to conform to DataSource protocol and implement the cellForRow method ? (in TableView i can skip the cellForRow when using static cells).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the official [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW1):

> **Every collection view must have a data source object.** The data source
>   object is the content that your app displays. It could be an object
>   from your app’s data model, or it could be the view controller that
>   manages the collection view. The only requirement of the data source
>   is that it must be able to provide information that the collection
>   view needs, such as how many items there are and which views to use
>   when displaying those items.