# Display a table (in the html/Excel spreadsheet meaning) in a iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have been looking around for solutions on how to do this but I am getting a bit confused.

I'd like to **display tables of data** in my app, not in the sense of Apple's TableView, more like tables you find in Excel or the  in HTML.
Moreover in my app I will have **multiple tables** like this in different pages, that I wish to **style the same way**, **not all with the same number of rows or columns**. Those tables might be displayed on the screen alongside images or texts, probably never on their own. (so I need an element I can put in a UIViewController)

Basically a table like this (I put this off Google Images because my data is confidential)
[image]

I have the theory on how to do this but I'm not sure it's right or exactly how to do it.

My theory is I should create a subclass of UICollectionView, let's call it MyTablesView. MyTablesView would have a variable named data. My pages/VC that contain a table will have an instance of MyTablesView and feed it data in this variable. MyTablesView takes care of styling and displaying this data.

I'm fairly new to Swift and I don't know exactly so I'm not sure on how to tackle this. I am very confused on how to code a UICollectionView. I tried to read this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1 but it's with a UICollectionViewController and not a UICollectionView so I'm not sure how to tweak it.

So for now this is all I have...
    class MyTablesView: UICollectionView{
      var data = [String]
    }
(I put string for now because I'm not 100% sure of the data that would be in the tables, it will probably end up being doubles, but I'll also need something for headers...)

So I guess my question is:
How do I subclass a UICollectionView properly to display the data that will be given to it by a ViewController?

Let me know if anything is unclear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the PG ?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, turns out I didn't search thoroughly enough on SO, because here is the answer I had been looking for: 
[How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift/31735229#31735229)

Since it's another Stack Overflow topic, should I copy the answer or trust Stack Overflow to keep the link alive?

---

The answer I linked to displays a grid of data, but I wanted a table, which means I had to tweak it a bit since I wanted rows so below is an overview of my code. Most of it is similar to the answer I linked to. The changes I made regards the data to display in a **multidimensional array**, which means I also had to add the **numberOfSectionsInCollectionView** method in my class and adapt the other methods accordingly.
I still need to do some styling to get it to look right.

1. In my storyboard I have a VC where I dragged a UICollectionView. In its first cell I dragged a UILabel.
2. The VC implements UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate and has a parameter named data containing the data to display.
   From the storyboard I ctrl+dragged the UICollectionView and named it mytable.

   ```
   class MyView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
     @IBOutlet weak var mytable: UICollectionView! 
     var data = [[String]]()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       data = [["first", "1", "2"], ["second", "3", "4"]]
     }

   // --- UICollectionViewDataSource protocol ---

     //returns number of sections = subarrays in data
     func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
       return data.count
     }

     //returns number of items in a section= number of elements in a subarray in data    
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return data[section].count
     }


     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       // get a reference to our storyboard cell
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableCells

       // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
       cell.myLabel.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]

       return cell
     }

   // --- UICollectionViewDelegate protocol ---
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       // handle tap events
       print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
     }
   ```

   }
3. I also created a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.
   From the storyboard I ctrl+dragged the UILabel from the first cell of the UICollectionView into my subclass and named it myLabel.

   ```
   import Foundation
   class MyTableCells: UICollectionViewCell {  
     @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel! 
   }
   ```

In the storyboard I hooked delegate and datasource to the VC (Select the UICollectionView, click on the circle and drag it to the VC)

I only did it for one of my VC for now, I might actually subclass UIViewController to be able to have multiple VC with this implementation I guess.