# Swift a two views within a collection view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, ios9

I want to know how to be able to use multiple views inside a collection view controller besides only having a collection view. I have looked at different tutorials but they only show me how to have two different views in different view controllers. I want to be able to put labels above my collection view cells. But it won't let me drag a normal view onto the collection view controller so I cannotput any labels above my cells this it what happens when I try to do it. The labels get pushed to the top left corner. Any help is greatly appreciated.[image: Image of view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UIViewController instead of a UICollectionViewController.
To do so you can follow the accepted answer here: [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift)