# Swift, CollectionView, fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I downloaded a collection of images and loaded them into a collectionView. I want to be able to add the individual item selected to an array I declared globally whenever I press on an individual cell so then I can loop through them to be deleted from core data later. This line prints fine in terms of the order of the item - print("You selected cell #(indexPath.item)!"), but the 2nd time I press another cell to add to the array, I get an *fatal error: Index out of range* error. I don't know what I'm getting this.

```
var selectedCell: [Int] =  []     -> Declared globally


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // handle tap events

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

        if self.selectedCell.contains(indexPath.item){
            print("Item already added")
        } else {
            self.selectedCell.append(indexPath.item)
        }

        if selectedCell.count > 0 {
            toolbarButton.title = "Remove Item"
        }

//        let selectCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
//        selectCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }
```

Comment: Which line gives the array index exception?

Comment: self.selectedCell.append(indexPath.item)

Comment: I suspect it to be some other line. append can't give you that exception. What are those two commented lines in your code? Why they are commented out?

Comment: They change the color of the background of the cell if they are selected.

Comment: When you declare selectedCell, do you also declare any special get / set / willSet / didSet code blocks?

Comment: No i don't set any of that.

Comment: Use the debugger - what is the value of `indexPath.item` when the crash occurs. And did you really mean `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath.item`? Also, this code will also only work for 1 section - you might want to add the entire `indexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 9.3, Xcode 7.3**

I honestly think that **"fatal error: Index out of range"** does not apply to the simpler array of integer indexes that you declared, I think that it is associated to the index of the collection view itself.

Looks like you are conforming to the various protocols of `UICollectionView`, namely `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate`, because you are at least receiving callbacks to the cell selected method.

First thing that jumps at me is...

Where is `title` property for `toolbarButton` declared, is it a custom subclass of `UIButton`, because `title` is not a set able property of standard `UIButton` class.  This is how you'd typically set the title of a `UIBUtton`...

```
self.toolbarButton.setTitle("Remove Item", forState: .Normal)
```

Another thing is,

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
```

The variable `cell` is never used in that function, it should give you a warning.

Also, check all of your uses of the array variable `selectedCell`, in the if statement where you check the count value you are not using `self.selectedCell` for example.  Not sure what this would do, but I think this would cause your array to get re-synthesized, so count will be reset each time.

*There are few other items that I don't understand, here is the code that I would use.  Please check your code and syntax.*

The following code works:

```
var selectedCell: [Int] =  []

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    // handle tap events

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

    if (self.selectedCell.contains(indexPath.item))
    {
        print("Item already added")
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectedCell.append(indexPath.item)
    }

    print("selectedCell.count: \(self.selectedCell.count)")

    if (self.selectedCell.count > 0)
    {
        self.toolbarButton.setTitle("Remove Item", forState: .Normal)

        print("selectedCell: \(self.selectedCell)")
    }
    else
    {
        //nil
    }
}
```

The output would look something like this:

[image]

Note: When you click the same cell twice it is not added (in this case 8), once you have at least 1 item in the array, then the button title changes.

If you still can not figure it out, then see this post, it explains how to implement a collection view very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/4018041

Hope this helps!  Cheers.