# how to create CollectionViewCell with text below them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view to show details of items and each item has a status or detail below it. How can i achieve this. the design is like[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the attached image for the same.

[image]

Comment: I want a distance of 8 points between each item  and distance of 24pts between each  row respectively. minimumInternSpacing property is giving some other results. Any help.

Comment: Try with section inset.

Answer (score 0):

In `CollectionViewCell` you can do like add `imageView` and below You can add `Label` inside the Cell

this link for Swift..https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `CollectionViewCell`. `CollectionViewCell` does not have default text `label` as in `UITableViewCell`.

Follow link [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift/31735229#31735229)