# Use one index from array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view where display weather data for the next four days. In this block

```
func prepareCollectionViewDataSource() {
        var x = self.city?.forecasts
        x?.removeFirst()
        self.otherDaysForecasts = x
    }
```

This is how x is looking like:

```
[0] : Forecast
      - temperature : 296.84199999999998 { ... }
      - maximum : 296.84199999999998 { ... }
      - minimum : 296.84199999999998 { ... }
      - description : "light rain" { ... }
      - icon : "10d" { ... }
      - humidity : 92.0 { ... }
      - pressure : 1021.4299999999999 { ... }
      - wind : 1.8600000000000001 { ... }
      - date : 2016-07-18 18:00:00 +0000
```

I remove the first day and display other four. From JSON I got weather data on every three hours. It's an array and I want to display only one data for each day.

Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: please add your json response to easily extract into those collection cells

Answer (score 1):

In collection view, first, you need to prepare your data and then populate it accordingly using `UICollectionViewDataSource`

Your data should be class variables so it is accessible from any methods in class

```
var forcastData = [] // this is your x, array of dictionary
```

Here is your `UICollectionViewDataSource`

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return forcastData.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        // Here is the main part to configure the cell
        let data = forcastData[indexPath.row]
        // let say you have label for temparature that we want to set from your data in json dictionary
        cell.temperatureLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f MB", data.["temperature"].double!)
        return cell
    }
}
```

There is simple guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift). Also try read more on custom cell for the `UICollectionView`