# Xcode - Swift arrange images in a grid 2x4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing a universal iOS app. I am looking to achieve the below grid layout using 8 images (inclusive of the text).

My skills of autolayout are poor, especially for universal apps. I would like the layout to remain for iPad and smaller screen devices, and scale the images accordingly.

I am unsure how to achieve this. Could you suggest a method and perhaps point me in the right direction by providing suggestions on methods to achieve this, such as UICollectionView or grid layout using autolayout.

[image]

Comment: What are you using for this? Show a little of your code

Comment: This is a mockup using Sketch. The navigation bar is all sorted.

Comment: Don't come here with no code that you've tried (or maybe not even code, but something you've tried in _Xcode_). We can't help you if you haven't attempted something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collection view! It's a great way to arrange things in a view like this that automatically adapts to screen size.

Apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Simple example you can follow  - [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift)

UICollectionView is a powerful tool, can be tricky to nail down at first but follow along on the tutorial and you should be able to make your design in no time!

Comment: Thanks Ethan. This helped tremendously.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Collection view is available as of iOS 6 so that shouldn't be a problem with any new app you're creating. One reason to use iOS 9 as a base version on new projects is UIStackView - it's an amazing tool that provides a ton of automatic spacing of UIView elements and the like.