# unable to select Item in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I tried to use this code for collectionView
[How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift)

but for `swift 3` I added these changes in viewController

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]


    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow // make cell more visible in our example project

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }
}
```

It works, but in debug area I am getting this

```
    2016-09-20 00:18:39.299329 retry[6595:491717] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:39.319250 retry[6595:491717] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:39.375574 retry[6595:491699] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:39.436027 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:39.689342 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:56.028502 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:56.031374 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:56.034089 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 00:18:56.035698 retry[6595:491572] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-20 02:07:46.530726 retry[6595:491572] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/joodi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DF7F969-AD53-4D2B-82B5-4999B5FC23E8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-09-20 02:07:46.531996 retry[6595:491572] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

also when I press any cell nothing happens, I think `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` not working

Comment: retry to make it .. and carefully implement

Comment: @NazmulHasan I fix the method `didSelectItemAt` and its work, but I still have some text in debug area, what this is thing?

Comment: Me also getting this on xcode 8

Comment: show  what are  you gating in the debug area

Comment: how you fix the method didSelectItemAtInedexPath ?

Comment: @MohanSingh How you fix it ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan the header of method was changed in swift 3, I just wrote it again with new style

Comment: @joda , No response i think my answers are not compatible with you!. just wanna response for my waste of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A.`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

If you need more about declaring functions then see on **[Apple Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)** documentation.

**B.Specify environment variables to disable unwanted logs**

1. go to **Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme** on Xcode Menu.

   [image]
2. In the **left column**, select the **Run** scheme action.
3. Click **Arguments** at the **top of the right** column.
4. To add an environment variable, click the Add button **(+)** at the bottom of the Environment Variables table and enter the variable name as `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and value as `DISABLE` or `disable`. Then click close.

   [image]

If you confused, then see my **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HndIYrGCfgU)**.

If you need More about Xcode, then see on apple **[Xcode Help](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)** page.

Comment: The suggested answer does not answer the question