# What is the best method to display information in a 4x4 grid with labels?

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch, layout

I am looking to display information (a 2-digit int) on an iOS app in a 4x4 grid design with a small label underneath each bit of data (the int's).

If I was to do this in Excel it would look like a 4x8 Grid (including text).

The data will all be pulled from an SQL database (different cells = different queries)

I have been trying to lay this out using 32 different 'labels' but getting the constraints correct is proving impossible.

Is there a different method I should be using in doing this? A table view, or stack view, or something completely different?

Comment: You can check the UICollectionView, that might be the answer you are looking for. Collection view is meant for grid kind of things

Comment: Thanks, does a Collection View object have to be inside a Collection View Controller? - as currently I already have a View Controller set up with a Scroll View inside of it

Comment: you can make your view controller a collectionview by making it conform to  the UICollectionView delegates. take a look at the answer code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift)

Comment: Yes collection view is written over scrollView, so like tableView, so collection view is having default scrolling, based on the content

Comment: Thanks Danoram, in looking at the example provided i think because of my data labels they might not 'fit' so stack views may be the way forward... i'll try those first.  Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will only have a 4x4 design, you use [stack views](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). You can embed the stackviews in each others.

You would create a first horizontal stack view. In this stack view, you add two stack views for the columns etc.

Comment: or 4 vertical stacks for my case in particular?

Comment: 4 vertical stacks containing a digit + label underneath. But you need to arrange them in a grid of 4x4, and you will achieve it by using stack views.

Answer (score 0):

If the grid is fixed, never scrolls, and never changes sizes then I agree with @Kamchatka, use nested stack views. (Say for example each row is a horizontal stack view and then you put those row stack views in a vertical stack view.)

If you need to be able to handle varying numbers of cells, or scrolling, then you should look at using a `UICollectionView`.