# Make collection view scroll left and right

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I followed the tutorial in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift). Currently, collection view scrolls up and down. Is there any way I can make the collection view scroll left and right instead? I would like the first cell shown on the left and the last cell shown on the very right.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    return cell
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting direction for collection view is very easy. I guess this is what you're looking for. Just change the direction to horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Mark as answered if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionViewFlowLayout -> setup Scroll direction

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617720-scrolldirection