# How to access UICollectionViewCell via UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` linked as a `@IBOutlet`. Now I want to access any of the cells inside (which are hidden). I.e. to change the color of the cell.

All methods I found need the IndexPath, but where do I get this from?

Comment: `Now I want to access any of the cells inside (which are hidden). I.e. to change the color of the cell.` Why do you want to change the color of something that is hidden?

Comment: @loki what you are try?

Comment: Don't change anything in the view (the cell) directly. Add a property to your model (the data source array), change that and reload the collection view. In `cellForItem` set the color according to the property's state.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) When you're asking a question, it helps to include what you've attempted so far (either code or research), which will help improve the chance of getting a good answer. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask when you ask your next question

Comment: @Larme: So it has a new color, when it gets visible again. Which can be later.

Comment: @YogendraGirase: What should happen is, that once i tap a button. A random tile of the CollectionView gets unhidden.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can create an IndexPath which are all listed on in the Initializers section of [IndexPath documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath).

For example if you wanted to access the first item in the first section you could use this initializer:

```
let index = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index)
```

Since you're new to Swift, it might also be worthwhile following through a few general examples and tutorials of using `UICollectionView`, here's a good starting off point: [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift).

Comment: Carefull: Is by "hidden" the author means not present on the screen, `cell` should be `nil` and won't be able to set anything.

Comment: @Larme interesting! _The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or index​Path is out of range._ ... I learnt something new :)

Comment: It's normal if you understood correctly the reuse of the cells. The cell you call that is out of screen may have been reused and serves currently for another indexPath.

Comment: does that mean, that hidden cells have no IndexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to access the cells on the collection view. So probably you want your view controller class to inherit from UICollectionViewController and then override the method cellForItemAt:

Something like:

```
class myViewController: UICollectionViewController, ... {
   ...
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      ...
   }
```

Try to create a new File, then choose cocoa class and then choose that it's a subclass of UICollectionViewController. The methods to override should be there, automatically.

Comment: well, I meant inside the UIViewController I have a @IBOutlet weak var that is linked to a Collection View. I never said anything about a ControllerView.

Comment: Maybe was a typo, as your question was edited. Thanks for clarification.