# UIcollectionview lagging while scrolling cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I am creating 7 cells using `UICollectionview`. When i scroll, the application works fine, but if i continue to scroll, it start to lag and the shadow(behind every cell) become more dark.

I think that the cell that disappear from the screen is not deleted and when i return back the program recreate a new one in the same position of the oldest one. is there any solution?

Screen before the scroll

https://ibb.co/dNQJ5k

Scree after the scroll

https://ibb.co/kjDAJ5

here's the code

```
class menuController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var coll_view: UICollectionView!

var array = [String]()
override  func viewDidLoad() {
    array = ["segue_menu_map", "segue_menu_camera"]
    coll_view.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) 
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.2*button.frame.width
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.tag=indexPath.row
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.4, height: 1.8)
    cell.clipsToBounds = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(collectionAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    print([indexPath.row])
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    button.setTitle(String(indexPath.row), for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    cell.addSubview(button)
    return cell
}



func collectionAction( sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag < 2{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: array[sender.tag], sender: nil)
    }

 }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: call `super.viewDidLoad()` from the `viewDidLoad` function. Also, the `collectionViewCells` are reused, and because you are the button in `cellForRowAt`, it is might not removed from the view hierarchy. Did you override `prepareForReuse` for the cells?

Comment: no i didn't. how can i do it?

Comment: I highly recommend to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift

Answer (score 1):

`collectionView.dequeueReusableCell` does *not* create a new cell every time. It reuses already created cells to improve performance. You are adding a button to the cell every time it's reused, this could mean that a single cell could have dozens/hundreds of buttons on it.

The solution is to make a subclass of UICollectionViewCell and put your set-up code there.

Comment: i make a subclass called "buttonCollectionView", now i have to send data (indexpath.row) from collectionview method of first class to this class. So i setup in collectionview method "let delegate = buttonCollectionView()" "delegate.button.tag = indexPath.row". now if i print delegate.button.tag it show me the number i want, but if i try to print button.tag in "buttonCollectionView" class it show me only 0 for each button.
How can i solve?
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i am scrolling the collectionView.
I had found two major problem and fixed this.

1. *I moved the code like create a button or something to the collectionviewcell .m file explicitly. This bring me smooth scrolling.*
2. *I delete shadow property of the cell.. trust me it removes the lag immediately.* 
   Now i dont know how to fix this problem with shadow offset. but upper case was fixed the lag.

And add this code in custom cell or cellforItem in main class:

for main class

```
cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

for custom cell

```
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```