# Reloading UICollection view after data parse

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, uicollectionview, xcode8

I am trying to dynamically update a uicollectionview. I used [this amazing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift) on how to create a simple uicollection.

It works great when using a static array of items. My issue - I would like to have the uicollection populate with data I parsed into a new array from my db. I am not sure how to reload the uicollection after parsing my json data.

**UPDATED CODE WITH ANSWER:**

```
import UIKit

class Books: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var bookscollection: UICollectionView!

    var user_id: Int = 0;

    //------------ init ---------------//

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        showtutorial()
        getuserid()
    }


    //------------ show books ---------------//

    var booknames = [String]()
    var bookcolor = [String]()
    var bookdescription = [String]()
    var bookid = [Int]()

    func posttoapi(){

        //show loading
        LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(view: self.view)

        //send
        let url:URL = URL(string: "http://www.url.com")!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let paramString = "user_id=\(user_id)"
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) in

            //hide loading
            LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()

            //no response
            guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                print("response error")
                return
            }

            //response, parse and send to build
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8);
            if let data = json?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8){

                let json = try! JSON(data: data)

                for item in json["rows"].arrayValue {

                    //push data to arrays
                    self.booknames.append(item["name"].stringValue)
                    self.bookcolor.append(item["color"].stringValue)
                    self.bookdescription.append(item["description"].stringValue)
                    self.bookid.append(item["id"].int!)

                    //reload uicollection 
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                        self. bookscollection.reloadData()  
                    })


                }

            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }




    //------------ collection -------------//

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("collection view code called")
        return self.booknames.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = bookscollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! BooksCell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.booknames[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project
        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }



    //------------ end ---------------//

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to show that `JSON` parsing code

Comment: Have you created the outlet for the collectionView then please show that code as well.

Comment: @andehlu fetching data from database or getting json response anything that involves some task which is time consuming should work on background and updating your user interface should work on main thread so use dispatch queue to reload data on main thread.

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma as I m,ewntioned below                     DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    })
                     still doesn't get rid of the ambiguous reference error on self.collectionView ...any thoughts?

Comment: @andehlu can you update question and show what and where you getting error?

Comment: @andehlu have you given connection for your collection view outlet to your class.

Comment: collectionView where is this outlet?

Comment: Updated with full code... I do not have an outlet for the collection view. But when I create one I get an error on collectionView.cellForItemAt

Comment: you need collection view outlet buddy and replace your collection view name with that outlet name and then show us what is the error.

Comment: @TusharSharma omg you were right. I was missing the outlet this whole time! thank you so much man.

Comment: @andehlu welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem i faced..your url having many images means reload t

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Correct Answer!

Comment: if correct answer means plz put the tick mark @andehlu

Comment: Actually this did work once i had the outlet in. Thank you.