# Swift 4: How to implement horizontal scrollable image gallery with edged and centered images?

Tags: ios, swift

I’ve been looking around the internet for a while, but haven’t came up to anything like what I’m imagining. I want to create a view that’s like the image here

[image: Taken from the Apple App Store]

Is a scroll view or collection view the answer?

Comment: A collection view is a scroll view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is a horizontal collection view with spacing between items and images having a corner radius

Comment: You could do it with a scroll view but a Collection view does a lot of the work for you. I agree with Sh_Khan. A collection view is the best fit.