# Reference UIImageView / UILabel within UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Is there an elegant way to reference `UIImageView` (or an `UILabel`) nested within `UICollectionView`? (say, using `.` notation)

That is, without subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` bolierplate, *only* for creating an `@IBOutlet`.
For example, at SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/6726199).

Would be good to see examples.

Comment: If you know the `indexPath`, then you can get the cell using `cellForRowAt` method right? Once you have cell, you should be able to access cell.imageView ?

Comment: Tried this. `imageView` in `cell.imageView` doesn't work by default. err: `Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'`

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant way to do this without subclassing `UICollectionViewCell`.

You *could* do it without subclassing - by adding the `UIImageView` programatically, then finding it (somehow) whenever you need it - but that's very much an iOS anti-pattern. (But that still wouldn't allow you to use dot-notation, because the child view isn't a property of `UICollectionViewCell`)

Comment: Also: as well as being an anti-pattern, you'll probably end up writing _more_ code, and it'll be less typesafe. Finally, you may have problems with cell reuse (because you'll need to explicitly find and remove those `UIImageViews` from the cells before they're reused).

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use dot notation. But you can assign some tag to the image UIImageView in storyboard. Like 123 here. and access it using that tag.

```
if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(123) as? UIImageView {
   //  imageView.image = some image 
}
```

I am not sure if this is a good pattern. But still you can get rid of the UICollectionViewCell boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to achieve that (I would not say that it is "elegant" and I would note that you should not do it most of the time) which is using the [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) property of the view:

> An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your
>   application.

Consider that you have the following cell:

[image]

What you could do is to select the image view/ label and from the interface build, go to the attribute inspector and set its tag:

[image]

Therefore, without the need of creating a `UICollectionViewCell` custom class what you should do in the `cellForItemAt` is to cast the views based on their tag values:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel

    // ...
}
```

Obviously, at this point keep in mind that the given tag value for `viewWithTag` *must* match the value set from the interface builder, as well as the sub casting, otherwise it will crash.