# CollectionView doesn't display

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard

As you can see in the first picture which i uploaded below.i have 3 segments.In the first segment collection view must be seems like that.However,when i click other segments it must disappear.Collection view must be between navigation view and contents view.Also, i uploaded another picture which is my storyboard.I'm waiting for your help.
Thank you!

[image: The Design should be like that]

[image: Picture of my Storyboard]

Comment: What the issue ? what you need ??

Comment: When the first segment selected Collection view needs to appear as in the first picture(between navigation view and Accounts container)

Comment: When i start the project, it doesn't appear.

Comment: Do you implement sizeForItem ??

Comment: Nope i just implemented numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAt

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
   return CGSize(width:<#width#>,height:<#height#>)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately,it doesn't work if you want i can upload my source on github

Answer (score 0):

this question is already answered in another place on stackoverflow

> [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift/31735229)

i think that is all you need to know